# IdSMTP fail to send email when executed inside a vps computer

Tags: delphi, indy

I want send a email *Hotmail* > *Gmail*, that contain a attach file and i mounted this code below and works fine when executed on my own computer, already when is executed inside a vps computer not sends any message.

////////////////////////////////////////////////

What is wrong with this code?

---

```
uses
  IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdExplicitTLSClientServerBase,
  IdMessageClient, IdSMTPBase, IdSMTP, IdMessage, IdAttachmentFile,
  IdSSLOpenSSL, IdGlobal;

procedure SendEmail(const Attach, Recipients: string; const Subject: string; const Body: string);
var
  SMTP: TIdSMTP;
  Email: TIdMessage;
  SSLHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin

  try

    SMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
    Email := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
    SSLHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);

    SSLHandler.MaxLineAction := maException;
    SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
    SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
    SSLHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
    SSLHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;

    SMTP.AuthType := satDefault;
    SMTP.IOHandler := SSLHandler;
    SMTP.Host := 'smtp.live.com';
    SMTP.Port := 587;
    SMTP.Username := 'test@hotmail.com';
    SMTP.Password := 'test123';
    SMTP.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;

    Email.From.Address := 'test@hotmail.com';
    Email.From.Name := 'TEST';
    Email.Recipients.EmailAddresses := Recipients;
    Email.Subject := Subject;
    Email.Body.Text := Body;

    if not FileExists(Attach) then
      Exit;

    TIdAttachmentFile.Create(Email.MessageParts, Attach);

    try

      SMTP.Connect;
      SMTP.Send(Email);
      SMTP.Disconnect;

    except
      Exit;
    end;

  finally
    SMTP.Free;
    Email.Free;
    SSLHandler.Free;
  end;
end;

SendEmail('c:\test.txt', 'recipient@gmail.com', 'Test SUBJECT', 'Test Body');
```

---

*EDITION:*

The error is:

> **Authentication unsuccessful**

[image]

```
    try
      SMTP.Connect;
      SMTP.Authenticate;
    except
      on E:Exception do
      begin
        MessageDlg('' +
          E.Message, mtWarning, [mbOK], 0);
        Exit;
      end;
    end;

    try
      SMTP.Send(Email);
      MessageDlg('Sent!', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
    except
      On E:Exception do
      begin
        MessageDlg('' +
          E.Message, mtWarning, [mbOK], 0);
      end;
    end;

  finally
    SMTP.Disconnect;
    SMTP.Free;
    Email.Free;
    SSLHandler.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: No Error messages? Obvious question, but, does 'c:\test\txt' actually exist on the vps machine?

Comment: @Dsm, yes exists.

Comment: Do you have the dlls that are required for ssl? Damn, this is so hard without error messages.

Comment: @Dsm, i edited the question.

Comment: @GolezTrol, i have the dlls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is clear from the error message that the server is rejecting your authentication attempt before sending the email.

Before I get into specifics for your issue, let me give you some information so you understand how `TIdSMTP` authentication works in general.

By default, the `TIdSMTP.AuthType` property is `satDefault`, and the `TIdSMTP.ValidateAuthLoginCapability` property is True.  This means the `TIdSMTP.Username` and `TIdSMTP.Password` properties are sent using an unsecure `AUTH LOGIN` command (which most servers will not accept without an established SSL/TLS session), but only if the server's `EHLO` reply indicates that `LOGIN` is an acceptable authentication (which many servers do not report, even if they do accept it).

So, it is possible that `TIdSMTP.Authenticate()` (which you do not need to call manually, `TIdSMTP.Send()` calls it for you) may not even attempt to authenticate with a server when `AuthType=satDefault`, and then a subsequent call to `TIdSMTP.Send()` can fail with an authentication error (you can verify this by assigning one of Indy's `TIdLog...` components to the `TIdSMTP.Intercept` property and then look at the actual SMTP commands that `TIdSMTP` sends).

So, try setting `TIdSMTP.ValidateAuthLoginCapability` to False so `TIdSMTP.Authenticate()` will always send `AUTH LOGIN` when `AuthType=satDefault`, regardless of whether the server reports it is acceptable or not.  If the server does not accept it, at least it will fail authentication at that stage, rather than at the `Send()` stage.

However, most SMTP servers nowadays accept/require stronger authentication schemes than `LOGIN`, such as `CRAM-SHA1` or `CRAM-MD5`.  So, you could set `AuthType=satSASL` instead, and then populate the `TIdSMTP.SASLMechanisms` collection with relevant `TIdSASL`-derived components (including `TIdSASLLogin` to handle `AUTH LOGIN` when supported), and link them to a `TIdUserPassProvider` to get the `Username` and `Password` (the `TIdSMTP.Username` and `TIdSMTP.Password` properties are not used during SASL authentications).

Now, that being said, I tested `TIdSMTP` with `smtp.live.com`, and it does, in fact, report support for `LOGIN` authentication after an SSL/TLS session is established, so `ValidateAuthLoginCapability` doesn't apply to that server.  The `AUTH LOGIN` command gets sent when using `AuthType=satDefault`, or when using `TIdSASLLogin` with `AuthType=satSASL`.

But, the server rejects my login attempts with `AUTH LOGIN` when using my *real* Hotmail password, and this is because my account has 2-Step Verification enabled.  So, in order for `TIdSMTP` to login correctly, I have to go into my Hotmail account using a web browser and create an **App Password** in the security settings, and then configure `TIdSMTP` to use *that* password instead of my *real* password.  Then `AUTH LOGIN` is successful.

You will have to do the same, if you have 2-Step Verification enabled on your Hotmail account.

```
SMTP.AuthType := satDefault;
SMTP.IOHandler := SSLHandler;
SMTP.Host := 'smtp.live.com';
SMTP.Port := 587;
SMTP.Username := 'real hotmail email here';
SMTP.Password := 'app password here'; // <--
SMTP.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
```

Note that the only other authentication scheme that `smtp.live.com` supports is `XOAUTH2`<sup>*</sup>, which does not require an App Password be created.  [Indy does not currently implementation `XOAUTH2`](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/192).  But there may be a 3rd party implementation floating around if you look around.  Or, you can try implementing a custom `TIdSASL`-derived component for it yourself.

<sup>*</sup> FYI, Gmail also supports `XOAUTH2` for SMTP and IMAP.

Comment: i haven't 2-Step Verification enabled in my Hotmail account. This error above is only when try send email from a vps computer, on my pc works fine.

Comment: I don't know what a VPS computer is, or how it differs from a standard computer.  But SMTP is a protocol, it works the same way on all computers and devices, and `TIdSMTP` implements SMTP commands only one way.  So either the SMTP server accepts the username/password you send to it, or it doesn't.  It shouldn't matter what kind of computer is sending it. You are just going to have to sniff the SMTP traffic from your VPS computer and compare it to the SMTP traffic from your PC, and see what is different about them.

Comment: i discovered that was a security reason where smtp server (Hotmail) not accept connections from a strange location, thank you anyway, i will accept your answer.